# How to remove definition In between lines by coc-nvim

Tags: vimrc, plugin-coc, original-vim

I want to remove the inline definition that come like this (underline parts):
[image]

These are coming due to coc-nvim and I don't want to see them.

How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add in your `~\coc-settings.json`:

```
    "inlayHint.enable": false,
```

You can get access to `~\coc-settings.json` by using the `:CocConfig` command.

If you want to toggle it off in the session you can do:

```
:call coc#config("inlayHint.enable", v:false)
:e %
```

Or either:

```
:call coc#config("inlayHint", {"enable" : v:false})
:CocRestart
```

Comment: Thank You !!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If the answer solve your problem don't forget to validate it (using the v mark)