# Help me remove feature in NVim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-coc, plugin

I've just used NVim lately and install some plugins Plugin List
[image]

And every function have some params name behind it . Anyone know where this comes from and how to remove it ? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/39475/23502) could provide you some hint.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)